# i need to convert my array styled adjacency matrix into vector styled (to make it look better)

Tags: c++, class, vector, graph

I am new in graph concepts i am just trying to learn it by writing small codes and playing with it. I have an adjacency matrix undirected graph class which is based on 2d array i want to convert it to 2d vectors.

i initialized a vector by doing `vector<vector<int>> graphed`. but i am not able to modify it in the constructor and the addedge() function is also misbehaving. The code is giving logical error and crashing. the display function is just a fancy display of the binary matrix. nothigs wrong there

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class my_graph{
    public:
        vector<vector<int>> graphed;
        int row=0;
        int col=0;
        my_graph(int size){
            int row=size;
            int col=size;
            // what am i supposed to type here to make the graphed 2d vector
            // size equal to the user provided size.
        }
        void add_edge(int i,int j){
            graphed[i][j]=1;//am i supposed to use pushback() function here?
            graphed[j][i]=1; // or is it fine?
        }

        void display(int size){
            cout<<" ";
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                cout<<" "<<i;
            }
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<" ";
            for(int i=0;i<2*size;i++){
                cout<<"-";
            }
            cout<<"\n";
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                cout<<i<<"|";
                for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                    cout<<graphed[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
        }
};

int main(){
    int v=6;
    my_graph g1(v);
    g1.add_edge(1,2);
    g1.add_edge(1,4);
    g1.add_edge(1,5);
    g1.add_edge(2,5);
    g1.add_edge(2,3);
    g1.add_edge(3,5);
    g1.add_edge(3,0);
    g1.add_edge(5,4);
    g1.add_edge(0,4);
    g1.add_edge(0,3);
    g1.display(v);
    return 0;
}

my desired output is

  0 1 2 3 4 5
 ------------
0|0 0 0 1 1 0
1|0 0 1 0 1 1
2|0 1 0 1 0 1
3|1 0 1 0 0 1
4|1 1 0 0 0 1
5|0 1 1 1 1 0

thanks for helping.
```

Comment: `graphed[row][col];` what do you think this does? Because it doesn't do that.

Comment: And the code you show is not "giving logical error and crashing" - it runs [just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/uL_iXJ). If you have a problem with changing the code to use `std::vector` then please show the code that has problems.

Comment: graphed[row][col]; initializes 2d array with the user provided size.for now i am keeping row and col same for simplicity making it a square matrix. I know i am not using any vectors because i am getting run time errors with it. i need you to convert this code from 2d array to wd vectors

Comment: `graphed[row][col];` does not initialize a 2D array of that size. It accesses the element at row `row` and column `col` (exactly the same thing you do in `display`) - and then it ignores that value. We will not completely rewrite this program for you to use `std::vector` instead - again, please **show the code that you get errors with**. It is impossible to tell you what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did.

Comment: In addition to use `std::vector`, you might then get rid of `row`/`col` member (equal to `graphed.size()`) and display doesn't need size parameter neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initialize a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, you can do the following:

```
    my_graph(int size){
        int row=size;
        int col=size;
        graphed = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(size, std::vector<int>(size, 0));
    }
```

This will set `graphed` to be a vector of `size` vectors that each contain `size` zeros.

It is common practice to use member initializer lists though:

```
    my_graph(int size)
      : row(size), col(size),
        graphed = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(size, std::vector<int>(size, 0))
    {
    }
```

Other than this, your code needs no changes to work with `std::vector`!

https://godbolt.org/z/lYcTnV

Comment: graphed = std::vector<int>(size, std::vector<int>(size, 0)); this line of code is giving me [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::vector(int&, std::vector<int>)'

Comment: @AdnanAhmed Yes I had a typo initially, it's already corrected.

Comment: graphed = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(size, std::vector<int>(size, 0)); can you please explain me this line of code please?

Comment: @AdnanAhmed It is explained in the answer already. Can you be more specific what confuses you? Have you looked at the documentation of `std::vector` or whatever material you are using to learn C++?

Comment: graphed = vector<vector<int>>(size, vector<int>(size, 0)); this line also works. now i get it. actually i was not familiar with 'std::' .